# In redux-form input type text field lose focus after 1st change?

Tags: redux-form

```
const renderInput = ({ input, label, meta }) => {
        return (
            <div className={`field ${meta.error && meta.touched ? 'error' : ''}`}>
                <label>{label}</label>
                <input type='text' {...input} autoComplete='off' />
            </div>
        );
    };
<Field name='title' component={renderInput} label='Enter Title ' />
```

Upon typing in input, text field loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
added in **renderInput** function input attribute
<input
                    type='text'
                    {...input}
                    autoFocus={meta.active}
                    autoComplete='off'
                    placeholder={label}
                />
it is working...
```